# Access Google Talk chat history

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-talk

I'm looking for a method to access [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/talk/about.html) chat history. Method to be used for an android device but does not have to be specific to it. I am looking for preferably an official method, but this is not required. AFAIK there is no official method. The method must pecifically not,

1. Through IMAP (requires chat and  label to be enabled)
2. Through Talk.apk's ContentResolver (requires that the talk.apk be installed)

unless it somehow bypasses the problems listed after the methods above.

Googles different Google Talk applications are able to do chat history but there is no documentation that im aware of to how this works.

Answer (score 12):

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) has a [getChatThreads()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmailapp#getChatThreads) API Call.

You're going to face issues with any of these methods. I think the best (of the bad) solutions is to use IMAP and include steps for enabling the Chat label to be accessed via IMAP. One nice thing about [OAuth 2.0 Gmail IMAP authentication](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol) is that it doesn't depend on the user turning IMAP on in GMail, it just works regardless of the user's IMAP setting.

Comment: Is there way to at least automate or Simi automate the process of enabling the label?  Checking the state of the label being able ect

Comment: You could provide the user with a direct link to the Settings -> Labels section of their Gmail: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#settings/labels. This might not work if they're logged into multiple accounts though.

Comment: I tried this before. This only worka(on a mobile device) if you request non mobile site else it redirects to mobile Gmail website. Still much to complicated to expect a user to do sadly.